# GE stackable washer dryer problem

Tags: washing-machine, washer

my GE washer dryer (model number GUD24ESSJWW) does a normal wash cycle, but when it comes to spin cycle, it won’t spin. After about 1-2 minutes, the machine will stop and spin button will flash. I’ve tried resetting my machine, taking out clothes and re-balancing, washing a new load, running it on empty machine; still occurs each time. Help! Thank you

Comment: Do these help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sy7ljWqBhls https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXUmWIk6G54